# B2C token failing to grant access to AAD-secured API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have an Azure App service secured by Active Directory authentication

I can successfully get tokens for Active Directory users that will authorise access requests to an API secured on the 'azurewebsites.net' domain

I wish to use B2C so people can sign up

I have created a B2C tenant, added API 'user_impersonation' scopes and granted access

I log in to the B2C tenant on my native app and receive a token

Unlike the AAD token, this one does NOT grant access to the secure API mentioned above

This is debug output returned in my Visual Studio instance when logging into the B2C account, confirming a token is being returned

```
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] Checking client info returned from the server..
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] Saving Token Response to cache..
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] Looking for scopes for the authority in the cache which intersect with https://alfretonb2c.onmicrosoft.com/backends/user_impersonation
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] Intersecting scope entries count - 0
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] Matching entries after filtering by user - 0
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] Saving RT in cache...
Info (False) MSAL 2.7.1.0 MSAL.Xamarin.iOS 12.2 [04/30/2019 20:15:01 - bbc5a55f-7c7a-4cf0-ac5a-ed39a614f17f] === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was returned with Expiration Time: 04/30/2019 21:15:01 +00:00 ===
```

The expected result is a token from the B2C directory that I can then use to send secure requests to an API secured by Active Directory authentication at App service level

Instead, I am simply receiving

```
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.
```

Comment: Have you checked (decode) your token Claims in `https://jwt.io/` || make sure it contains this  `"scp": "user_impersonation"`

Comment: The problem could be that your API is secured against AAD, and not Azure AD B2C. AAD issues different tokens then Azure AD B2C. You'll need to update your AAD config page to include the B2C information. see if this [link helps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-mobile-app), another customer with a similar issue found it helpful.